# Was Douglas Adams specifically joking about British small talk?

Tags: inspiration, quotes, the-hitchhikers-guide-to-the-galaxy, douglas-adams

There's this paragraph in the book:

> “One of the things Ford Prefect had always found hardest to understand about humans was their habit of continually stating and repeating the very very obvious, as in It's a nice day, or You are very tall or Oh dear you seem to have fallen down a thirty-foot well, are you all right?”

Am I correct that Douglas Adams was joking about how British people talk to each other (like, 'Are you all right') using this paragraph? Or is this paragraph just a simple joke without mocking the Brits' culture?

Comment: Hey Douglas Adams, we have a question for you, but you appear to be quite dead. Sorry for the bother.

Comment: I wouldn't say this behavior is limited to British people.

Comment: it's a comedy trope called the rule of three - http://kenlevine.blogspot.com/2013/07/the-comedy-rules-of-threes.html, https://entertainism.com/rule-of-three-in-comedy. - the joke isn't about british culture per se

Comment: Just a bit of tomfoolery, innit?

Comment: @NKCampbell - Like Hotblack Desiato, he's only dead for tax reasons.

Comment: "Are you all right" — do we say at that a lot? Sure, we say it when we find people who've fallen down a thirty-foot well, but I figure that's generalisable.

Comment: The last of the 3 has a tiny, tiny hint of [English understatement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_understatement)

Comment: Oddly enough, retired drummer Bev Bevan (who is English) remarked that Americans are masters at making small talk with complete strangers.

Comment: TIL there's a Wikipedia article for "English understatement."

Comment: @NKCampbell Also oddly enough, Hotblack Desiato owned an estate agents (tr: realtors) in North London in the 1980s.

Comment: The use of "are you all right?" as a sort of greeting for someone who's clearly not all right may not be exclusively British, but it's certainly pretty common in Britain.

Comment: The "You are very tall" one was quite probably a personal annoyance as he was in fact very tall.

Comment: @user_1818839 -and they're still going strong. Adams got the name from their Islington branch, being as he lived in Islington at the time & 'just liked the name'. I bet the company doesn't object to the 40 years of free advertising ;))

Comment: The weather is quite fine, today, if I may say so. Very much indeed. Quite fine. Though I suppose that depends not only on when you are, but also where you are. But I am here, and now, and therefore, the weather is just as I say it is, and it is quite fine.

Comment: "Oh dear" is a dead giveaway that the speaker is not from America; Americans are neither  that subtle nor that polite. The American equivalent would be "Jesus F. Christ, that looked scary! Are you, like, OK? Hang tight, bro, I'm gonna get you." Because Americans are also very pragmatic.

Comment: Can I give a nod here please to the somewhat earlier "How To Be An Alien" by George (György) Mikes. Mikes was of course Hungarian, but he took a similar approach to DNA: highlight cultural peculiarities by gently poking fun. Apparently some British were not amused...

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica - There's also a certain pragmatism in seeing if the victim declares himself well, then going about your day & leaving him to it ;) Jolly good. Toodle-pip, old chap. Should I let Marjorie know you might be late for tea?

Comment: 42 is the right answer

Answer (score 66, accepted):

At the time he wrote the original radio series and first novel, Adams had lived his entire life in England, and was writing for a British audience, so a lot of the cultural references are based on that culture. For instance, there are jokes about tea, gin and tonic, and a key plotline in one of the later books revolves around cricket; an American author might instead have referenced coffee, whisky, and baseball.

The distinction between mocking *human* behaviour and mocking *British* behaviour is therefore rather blurred, since humanity is represented almost entirely by British people (Arthur and Trillian) and people who've visited Britain (Ford and, briefly, Zaphod).

Probably the most parsimonious explanation is that this passage is mocking how *people Adams knew* talked to each other, and those people happened to be British as well as Earthlings.

Comment: But this kind of smalltalk hardly seems specific to British people. It's certainly common in America, too. If he thought it was targeting Britishisms, that would only be because he wasn't very worldly.

Comment: "people happened to be British as well as Earthlings." - probably Earthlings, though as his books show, it's very hard to tell.

Comment: @Barmar Well, that's kind of what I'm saying: if the _reader_ sees it as a Britishism, that's more likely because Adams was British than that he was consciously comparing the British to anyone else.

Comment: As an American reader of Adams, I just saw it as a humanism. There were lots of other references that seemed more specifically British.

Comment: Don't you mean "...happened to be British as well as Golgafrinchams."?

Comment: If you are talking about *Life, The Universe, and Everything*, didn't the entire book's premise revolve *around* a joke involving cricket rather than *having* a joke about cricket? :)

Comment: Its worth nothing that British people mocking British people and British-isms has been a national pastime for most of recorded British history…

Comment: Interesting thing to note is that in the most common Dutch translation of the books, everything has been Dutchified. The names have changed (Arthur Dent is Hugo Veld), as have the in-jokes (Ford Prefect becomes Amro Bank; a name of a bank) and tea is replaced with coffee, cricket with a Dutch sport that I forgot. No other book I know did that; for Harry Potter the names were Dutchified but the setting is still England.

Comment: _"Adams had lived his entire life in England,"_ - **Are you sure?** According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy#Background) and my own copy of H2G2, the book was inspired by Adams lying drunk in a field near **Innsbruck** while hitchhiking **around Europe**, carrying a copy of the _Hitch-hiker's Guide to Europe_.

Comment: @NigelTouch True. As far as I know, though, England was always _home_ to him (he later lived in LA for a while, which is why I put a timeframe on it), and where he spent most of his time. I certainly can't think of any references to Austrian behaviour, or others from his travels; the only specifically non-British reference that comes to mind is the running joke of "Belgium" being a galactic swear-word.

Comment: One small improvement: as an American he might have mentioned beer not whiskey. The former is (to my knowledge as a non-drinker) a much more common drink in the U.S.

Comment: @bob Beer is pretty universal. Arthur and Ford are drinking beer in the first or second scene (back when a five pound note was far too much for six pints, rather than barely enough for one!) Gin and tonic is more culturally specific, rather than common as an order at the bar.

Comment: @TripeHound Well, by that logic I should say "Mesopotamian" not "British" 

Comment: @IMSoP Agreed. If the writer wanted a stereotypical American scene or something in the West then whiskey yes. If they were just an American writer writing without trying to be stereotypical then I still think beer would be the choice over whiskey. But I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Probably mocking, but gently mocking.  When someone has fallen down a 30' well, do you say 'shall I call an ambulance' or 'are you all right'?  Depending on the injuries, one is an over-reaction and one an under-reaction. It is possible to move straight to the most dramatic (ambulance, undertaker) or possible to just ask.  Yes, it is funny that 'are you all right' (the traditional British comment) is the same phrase you would use if they *hadn't* fallen down a well.

As to the first phrases, fundamentally - the point of small talk is that it is 'small' i.e. not meaningful.  If one takes it as it is meant, no one minds, as at least you are talking, rather than shuffling your feet and being embarrassed, and can then move on to 'big' talk, dates, marriage, children or what you will.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.   The question was asking if the quote is particularly mocking _the British_.  Your answer doesn't suggest that this is a specifically British way of speaking, or just generally how small talk works.  You should [edit] your answer to more clearly reply to the question.